# Networking and Threads in Android Apps

Tags: android, networking

I know that i must use threads to use internet in Android application, but i don't know how to write it.
I have one class call "JabberSmackAPI" - on this class i have Login,send and receive functions via XMPP.

And i have one button on my app, when i press the button it should login to googleTalk account.

This works well on Java project ( i can login and send messages) but not on Android app project.
i receive this error: "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException".

My class is:

```
public class JabberSmackAPI 
{
    XMPPConnection connection;

    public void login(String userName, String password) throws XMPPException
    {
   ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("talk.google.com",5222,"gmail.com");



        connection = new XMPPConnection(config);

    connection.connect();
    SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);
    connection.login("email", "password");



    }

    public void sendMessage(String message, String to) throws XMPPException
    {
        Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat); 
        msg.setBody(message); 
        connection.sendPacket(msg);
        listeningForMessages();

    }




    public void disconnect()
    {
    connection.disconnect();
    }


    public void listeningForMessages() {
        PacketFilter filter = new AndFilter(new PacketTypeFilter(Message.class));
        PacketCollector collector = connection.createPacketCollector(filter);
        while (true) {
            Packet packet = collector.nextResult();
            if (packet instanceof Message) {
                Message message = (Message) packet;
                if (message != null && message.getBody() != null)
                    System.out.println("Received message from "
                            + packet.getFrom() + " : "
                            + (message != null ? message.getBody() : "NULL"));
            }
        }
    }
```

My app code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    Button btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);




}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId()==R.id.button1)
    {
        try{
            Toast.makeText(this, "T", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



             JabberSmackAPI c = new JabberSmackAPI();
             c.login("username", "password");



        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Error","Error in code:"+e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main application thread should only be used for interface-related work. You need to use [multithreading](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#threading), since networking is not allowed at all on the main thread of Android applications. Since your app requires a persistent data connection, [AsyncTasks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) won't work either, since they are single-serving - fire, get result and close connection.

Comment: i tried it but it didn't work. i don't know what code (from my code) should be under "AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>" and what code should be under "onPostExecute" and so on.

Comment: Hmm, now that I read more carefully your code, you want a persistent connection running. That won't work with AsyncTasks - they are only for finite requests (onPostExecute fires after the connection has ended). You will need to start a new thread for that. You will have to read something like http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#threading.

Comment: See my updated answer, but this is not the place for a tutorial on Threading.

Comment: There you go - http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#threading. If you find my answer helpful, you could mark it as the selected answer. Also, if you have any further (more specific) questions, feel free to continue using SO :)

Comment: i tried to do that as it written in the site you sent me. but it still not working :( look here below i put my new code and the errors.

Comment: i'm trying to solve this problem so many days and can't understand the problem.. need you help

Comment: Glad you made it work :) The most important thing is to understand your problem and read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Means exactly what it says - don't do network operations on the main/ui thread